# how can I change the font size in chapter title page?

Tags: formatting, packages, fontsize, templates

I use this template for a master's thesis, how can I Change font size and rank in center of a title page in each chapter as shown in the picture .

I want to Move the chapter title in the middle of the page and make a space between Chapter 2 and the chapter title
[image]

And

I use the package of `\fancyhdr` to put a line at the top of the page with the chapter title.But the font is large. How to reduce the font size as shown in the picture

The problem is that the title of the chapter exceeds the page limits on the contents page. It has a large volume at the top of the page. Is it a solution !!

```
         \documentclass[14pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{extreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{microtype}%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark }
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\thispagestyle{empty}\sffamily\bfseries\Huge\centering}{\thechapter}{1em}{\textls[40]}[\clearpage]
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [display]
    {\centering\Huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
    {12pt}
    {\Large}
    [\clearpage]{0pt}

\chapter{EXACT METHODS TO COMPUTE SYSTEM RELIABILITY}
%\input{chapters/chapter02}

\chapter{EXACT METHODS TO COMPUTE SYSTEM RELIABILITY POLYNOMIAL}
%\input{chapters/chapter03}

\chapter{Chapter Four Title}
%\input{chapters/chapter04}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Can I add a frame to the chapter title page?
[image]

Comment: `fancyhdr` is not done for that. You should take a look at `titlesec` to customise chapter titles.

Comment: @Bernard can you make an example

Comment: I don't have time at the moment (going to sleep…), but I'll try to post one tomorrow. Do you want to have a frame around the whole title page (and the chapter body to begin next page?)

Comment: `\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\leftmark}` or whatever? Why do you define the `\chapter` style and then immediately redefine it? In any case, where you have `\Huge`, change it to `\large` or `\normalsize` or `\tiny` or whatever.

Comment: Use `\titlespacing` to control the spacing. (I think. I have eliminated `titlesec` from my own stuff, but I think that's right. The documentation covers it along with the `\titleformat` command you're already using. I would advise against centring it vertically. If you do centre vertically, I would definitely not draw the box you are considering. (Not for TeXnical reasons. Aesthetic.) Vertical centring looks like 1995 Word to me.

Comment: The frame will not look good with horizontal centring, either, IMNSHO.

Comment: @cfr Thanks a lot .. I'm starting at Latex .. I just want it for aesthetic reasons

Comment: This question contains three or four separate questions that should be posted seperately.

Comment: You want that ugly frame to make the document look nicer? Oh my.

Comment: Off-topic: Why is there so much extra vertical and horizontal whitespace in your `enumerate` environment?